# No desktop after enabling root in Ubuntu!

Tags: unity, root

I have enabled root account on Ubuntu 14.10. After that, I logged out and logged in, but there is no desktop and no bars. I tried opening a terminal using keyboard shortcut but nothing is working. I can't see anything on the screen.

How should I restore my Desktop?

Comment: simply enabling the root account will not do this, there must be an additional problem. Check your X session logs for errors ( ~/.xsession-errors)

Comment: But I didn't install or do anything before I rooted it.

Comment: Check the logs for errors and check the ownership and permissions of all the files in your home directory `sudo chown -Rv your_user:your_user /home/your_user`

Comment: I know you said you tried a terminal but try again with ctrl + alt + T and if it opens run sudo gedit ~/.xsession-errors Are there any errors ? Add them to your question

Comment: If you still cant get a terminal, ctrl + alt + F1, will go to a "hard" terminal (no desktop at all), log in here and run- sudo nano ~/.xsession-errors -and post any errors for this and  bodhi.zazen's request sudo chown -Rv your_user:your_user /home/your_user

Comment: @markkirby Are you asking for `.xsession-errors` in the user's home directory (in which case `sudo` should be unnecessary even if a file like `.Xauthority` is root-owned -- but [if `sudo` is to be used, it should be `sudo -H` or `-sudo -i` for running `gedit`](https://askubuntu.com/q/270006/22949)) or `.xsession-errors` in `root`'s home directory (in which case `sudo -H gedit /root/.xsession-errors` should be used instead)? **Muhammad al Jayyosi**: Exactly what steps did you use when you enabled the root account?

Comment: @EliahKagan Sorry I can no longer remember the context of this it was 15 days ago and I revived no feedback but you may be right that it seems the OP is using a root profile so he should  sudo -H gedit /root/.xsession-errors

Comment: I do the following:   sudo -i     then:   sudo passwd root     then i put a new password.then i closed terminal and logged out